# NetLogo: Asking a limited number of turtles, ranked by the value of a variable

Tags: constraints, netlogo, ranking

I am trying to model capacity constraints and priorities in NetLogo (5.3.1, on Mac Sierra). It comes down to asking a limited number of turtles (say `n`) to do certain things, and choosing those turtles so that (1) they satisfy a certain conditios and (2) they are the `n` turtles with the maximum value of variable `my-variable`.

I am trying to do this by:

```
let subset-of-turtles turtles with [ condition-variable = some-value ]
ask max-n-of n subset-of-turtles [ my-variable ] [< do something >]
```

But it has multiple issues.

First, if no turtle satisfies the condition that `[ condition-variable = some-value ]`, NetLogo throws up an error

> Requested n random agents from a set of only 0 agents.

I tried solving by inserting a line before the `ask` command:

```
let subset-of-turtles turtles with [ condition-variable = some-value ]
if subset-of-turtles != nobody [
  ask max-n-of n subset-of-turtles [ my-variable ] [< do something >]
  ]
```

But it does not work:

```
observer> show turtles with [ condition-variable = some-value ]
observer: (agentset, 0 turtles)
observer> let subset-of-turtles turtles with [ condition-variable = some-value ] show subset-of-turtles != nobody
observer: true
```

NetLogo considers that an empty agentset is still an agentset, so it will pass the test of being different from `nobody`.

Second, even when there are some turtles that do meet the condition, NetLogo will throw up the same error if they are fewer than `n`. My model is a growth model, in which capacity is meant to be sufficient at the beginning, and then to hit the constraint. So, this will happen in every single run of the model.

I would like NetLogo to execute the command in the `ask` block at most `n` times. Suppose there are `m` turtles that satisfy the condition:
 1. If `m <= n`, execute the command on all `m` turtles
 2. `If m > n`, execute the command of the `n` turtles with the highest values of `my-variable`. Can anybody advise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, I would not recommend testing whether `count <agentset> = 0` since NetLogo still needs to construct the agentset to count it. However, there is a very convenient `any?` reporter for this task. So, try the following modification of your original code:

```
let subset-of-turtles turtles with [ condition-variable = some-value ]
if any? subset-of-turtles [
  ask max-n-of n subset-of-turtles [ my-variable ] [< do something >]
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks Jen. Will try it now. :-)

Comment: Oh right, of course. This is the better way, thanks Jen.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this setup:

```
turtles-own [
  condition-variable
  my-variable
]



to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  crt 10 [
    setxy random 30 - 15 random 30 - 15 
    set condition-variable random 2
    set my-variable 1 + random 10
  ]

end
```

<del>First, You can use `count` as a quick check of whether an agentset is empty, and use that as your conditional instead.</del>

Don't do this; as suggested by @JenB in the accepted answer, use the `any?` primitive instead.

Second, you can use `ifelse` to say something like "If there are fewer turtles in the subset than n, only ask the turtles in the subset. Else, ask n turtles in the subset."

```
to go

  let n 5
  let subset-of-turtles turtles with [ condition-variable = 1 ]

  ;;  obtain the number of turtles in the subset
  let subcount count subset-of-turtles

  ;; If there are more than 0 turtles in the subset, do the following
  if subcount > 0 [
    ;; If n is greater than the number in the subset, only ask the subset
    ifelse n >= subcount [
      ask max-n-of subcount subset-of-turtles [ my-variable ] [
        set size 2
      ]
    ]
    ;; If n is NOT greater than the number in the subset, ask n of the subset
    [
      ask max-n-of n subset-of-turtles [ my-variable ][
        set size 2
      ]
    ]
  ]  
end
```

Comment: Luke, I do not know how to thank you. This is a very careful, well explained answer. I will immediately try to implement it in the context of the model and get back to you. I have upvoted it, but my reputation is too low to publicly affect its score.

Comment: No problem Alberto- I hope it works. If not, feel free to ask follow-up questions. If the answer does solve your issue, you should accept it to "close" the question.

Comment: I still have issues. Thanks for your offer! My brain is fried now – I'll sleep on it and retry debugging tomorrow.

Comment: Luke, I have tested the code in a barebones version of the model and it works, so I accepted your answer, with thanks. My model itself behaves erratically, with the action <do something> performed where you would not expect it to and vice versa. I must have another issue I was not aware of. Would it be all right for me to ask a new question, once I can identify the problem?

Comment: Alberto, you are welcome to but I think in general it is best to ask a new question, firstly so that it is one issue per item but also because far more people will see a new question than a new comment.

Comment: Absolutely. I think I got the second problem nailed down. I am thinking in Python (with lists) rather than in NetLogo (with agentsets). It's more elegant to refactor the code so that it is more NetLogo-ish. I also used `any?` as suggested by @JenB .

Comment: Good call, that is definitely the more efficient way to deal with the first part of your problem!